# How to capture animated GIF and show still image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, animated-gif

Is there any way to capture animated image and make it as still image(PNG/JPEG)?

I want to capture below animated image in order to show still image of it. So, that I can add play button to toggle GIF image and still image.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="image_wrapper">
    <img class="animated_gif" src="http://i.imgur.com/zY4nD.gif" />
    <img class="still_img" src="" />
</div>
<a href="#" class="play_btn">Play/Pause</a>
```

**CSS**:

```
.image_wrapper{
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    background: #ddd;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    padding:10px;
}

.animated_gif{
    width:100%;
    height:150px;
    display:none;
}

.play_btn{
    background:#2FB82B;
    padding:5px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-radius:4px;
    margin: 42px;
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
}

.play_btn:hover{
    background:#4DD849;
}
```

[**JSFiddle Code**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishan152/opog993q/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/opog993q/3/)

```
$('.play_btn').on('click', function() {
    $('img').toggle();
})
```

Comment: yes. this is fine. But, I want to capture GIF image as still image.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a way to implement modification of animated GIF playback in Javascript reliably*. If a server-side solution is available to you, you could convert the gif to a video supported by `<video>` and implement controls in that manner.

*There are some projects that use a hack involving `<canvas>` to grab frames from a `gif`, but the behavior is not deterministic.